# Applying where condition when using pandas read_sql_table() -SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to use SQLAlchemy and Pandas to read a table from a Posgresql database into a Pandas dataframe using  read_sql_table(). The SQL query to the database is similar to this:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM my_table WHERE col1=='value'
```

I tried this code to get the Pandas dataframe from the table:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_uri = environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)

table_df = pd.read_sql_table(
'my_table',
con=engine,
schema="public"
columns=['col1','col2'])
```

This code works but how can I apply the condition, similar to WHERE in the SQL query, and filter the dataframe based on that condition?
I don't want to load the dataframe first in memory, I want to do it while querying the database.

Comment: Use `read_sql_query()` and pass it the SELECT statement that includes the WHERE clause.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks! I ended up using read_sql_query. however I am still interested in a way to avoid writing any SQL code.

Comment: Do you mean creating a query using SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression language, e.g., `qry = team.select().where(team.c.id == 1)` and then passing it to `pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)`? Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment to the question, you can use `read_sql_query()` to filter your results. If you want to avoid passing a raw SQL statement to the function you can create the query using SQLAlchemy Core and pass that instead:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

team = sa.Table("team", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
qry = sa.select(team.c.city, team.c.name).where(team.c.id == 1)
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
print(df)
"""
      city    name
0  Calgary  Flames
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:senha@db', echo=False)

team = sa.Table('oracle_table', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine, schema='db')
qry = sa.select(team.c.column_a, team.c.column_b).where(
                team.c.column_b == 'OPTION')
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
print(df)

engine.dispose()
```